# Can i use an html page as content of another HTML page..?

Tags: html

Im new to programming..Can anybody help me out please ....

im using an html to display an image later i want to display another html on the first html so i need to set second html as transparent. so the image in the first html looks like a background image....

is it possible...?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you actually ***could*** use an `<iframe>` containing the second page in a floating `<div>`-element. But as always, it's not always good just because it exists or because it was technically possible.

Except for the use of frame, you should never have more than one `<html>` and never more than one `<body>`

It would be the best to have something like this:

```
<html>
    <head><!-- header goes here --></head>
    <body style="background-image: url('first.png');">
        <img src="second.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sure you could extract the css-part into a css-file. And you could set the style-attribute for another tag as well, it doesn't forcibly has to be `<body>`

hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for quick response ..
The second html is generated by the eXe tool and  it contains text and images...for background image i used UIImageView instead of html. now the html has to be transparent so while scrolling the html page i can see the background image

by using the <body style="background-color:transparent"> tag its workin but the text parts in the html r generated by eXe in SCORM format are having some background color....
 i want that color also to be transparent to see the background image.....
hmmm.... is it possible..?

Thank u

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you any further because i neither know eXe/SCORM nor Apple/iPhone-specific...

Answer (score 2):

You can't. But if you just want a background image, you can accomplish this by using CSS and the `background-image`. See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

With a scripting/programming language you can.

In ASP.NET you can read the contents of an html file and put it inside your current page.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like iframe is what you are looking for. Perhaps the use of the words "on" and "transparent" are throwing me off. It sounds like you want to have two HTML pages, with the content from one appearing in front of the other but transparent? In that case I think CSS z-index might help you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Stacking_context_example_1